# Calling function in PHP class not working

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a a class stored in path `plug/PHPDocumentParser/DocumentParser.php`:

```
namespace LukeMadhanga;
class DocumentParser {
    static function parseFromString($string) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I want to call the class and function. I run this in a file that's stored at the base folder:

```
include_once("plug/PHPDocumentParser/DocumentParser.php");
$docObj = new DocumentParser();
$docText = $docObj->parseFromString('hello world');
```

I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DocumentParser' not found
```

I am pretty sure the problem is how I call the class, correct?

Comment: Did you try to define namespace?

Comment: are you sure that `DocumentParser.php` is included? no warning from `include_once`?

Comment: This is a path problem check your path again.

Comment: @Mark Ah I think you are on it. I have updated my question with the namespace, can you please post an answer outlining how to call it properly?

Comment: aaaaaand namespace it's. `$docObj = new \LukeMadhanga\DocumentParser();`

Comment: `$docObj = new LukeMadhanga\DocumentParser();`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling static function in wrong way. Try

```
DocumentParser::parseFromString()
```

Also use require_once, you will know if it was included correctly. (maybe path is wrong.)

Edit : Ok, you added namespace now - it should be `\LukeMadhanga\DocumentParser::parseFromString()` thats also why you dont get instance of DocumentParser using *new*.
Of course you can always add *use* keyword at top of your file to include your namespace.

Comment: `include_once()` will also throw errors if the path is wrong.

Comment: So do you mean that I run the function like this: `$text = LukeMadhanga\DocumentParser::parseFromString('hello world')`

Comment: @JayBlanchard well, to be precise include gives you warning, not error.

Comment: The current problem is indeed the namespace. The next problem would have been the incorrect invocation of the method, so this is the correct solution.

Comment: Well yes @Vini - to split hairs, you're correct. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @vini Could you confirm if this is the correct approach: `$text = LukeMadhanga\DocumentParser::parseFromString('hello world');`

Comment: I think you are missing one "\" before LukeMadhanga. Just try it, that would be faster than waiting for me to replay ;)

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark my answer. Thanks.